# Edit data with ajax Post

Tags: jquery, ajax

I try to change data in a form and then save. Instead of changing it adds a record..

This is my script:

```
$('#UpdateObject').click(function () {

    var ObjnameEntered = $("#NameOB")[0].value;
    var BasenameEntered = $("#selbaseID")[0].value;
    var idsave = $("#labelobID")[0].value;
    var kaartX = $("#mapx")[0].value;
    var kaartY = $("#mapy")[0].value;
    var picture = $("#trainpicname")[0].value;
      $.ajax({
        url: '/api/Traininglocation/' + idsave +'/',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ TrainLocationName: ObjnameEntered, TrainBaseID: BasenameEntered, TrainXcoord: kaartX, TrainYcoord: kaartY, TrainPicture: picture }),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: $('#doebam').show()
    });
});
```

The controller:
i used the put methode then i get a 405 error after publish my project..

> error on the server hosing :
>   Event code: 4005 
>   Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid. 
>   Event time: 2-12-2013 16:21:56 
>   Event time (UTC): 2-12-2013 15:21:56 
>   Event ID: 817a9928807646699d3d2ef795ae478d 
>   Event sequence: 2 
>   Event occurrence: 1 
>   Event detail code: 50201

// PUT api/Traininglocation/5

```
    public HttpResponseMessage PutTrainLocation(int id, TrainLocation trainlocation)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && id == trainlocation.id_trainlocation)
        {
            db.TrainLocation.Attach(trainlocation);
            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(trainlocation, EntityState.Modified);

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }

    // POST api/Traininglocation
    public HttpResponseMessage PostTrainLocation(TrainLocation trainlocation)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.TrainLocation.AddObject(trainlocation);
            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, trainlocation);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = trainlocation.id_trainlocation }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

Who can help me?

Comment: if it adds a record in database...that has nothing to do with javascript, it's how you handle the request at server

Comment: I would suspect that either `idsave` is empty or whatever is handling `/api/Traininglocation/{id}` has a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my controller :
where PutTrainLocation to PostTrainLocation.
Thanks for response!!

```
    public HttpResponseMessage PostTrainLocation(int id, TrainLocation trainlocation)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && id == trainlocation.id_trainlocation)
        {
            db.TrainLocation.Attach(trainlocation);
            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(trainlocation, EntityState.Modified);

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```